# Regular expression to match single bracket pairs but not double bracket pairs

Tags: javascript, regex

Is it possible to make a regular expression to match everything within single brackets but ignore double brackets, so for example in:

```
{foo} {bar} {{baz}}
```

I'd like to match foo and bar but not baz?

Comment: Sorry, should have said. JavaScript.

Comment: @stovroz: Bummer. Then you don't have lookbehind assertions.

Comment: @stovroz: You should *always* mention the language, even if you don't think it will be relevant.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To only match `foo` and `bar` without the surrounding braces, you can use

```
(?<=(?<!\{)\{)[^{}]*(?=\}(?!\}))
```

if your language supports lookbehind assertions.

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=      # Assert that the following can be matched before the current position
 (?<!\{)  #  (only if the preceding character isn't a {)
\{        #  a {
)         # End of lookbehind
[^{}]*    # Match any number of characters except braces
(?=       # Assert that it's possible to match...
 \}       #  a }
 (?!\})   #  (only if there is not another } that follows)
)         # End of lookahead
```

**EDIT:** In JavaScript, you don't have lookbehind. In this case you need to use something like this:

```
var myregexp = /(?:^|[^{])\{([^{}]*)(?=\}(?!\}))/g;
var match = myregexp.exec(subject);
while (match != null) {
    for (var i = 0; i < match.length; i++) {
        // matched text: match[1]
    }
    match = myregexp.exec(subject);
}
```

Comment: Looking good, but what does the colon do in your JavaScript version? My real world subject happens to contain one before a bracket, :{foo}, and the colon is getting matched when it shouldn't.

Comment: Scrap that. The colon was a red herring. The character before the { is always getting pulled in.

Comment: @stovroz: Exactly. By the way, I've made a small edit to the regex that will now also work if two sets of braces are directly adjacent to each other.

Comment: this part: "[^{}]*    # Match any number of characters except braces" . How do I include the braces?

Answer (score 3):

In many languages you can use lookaround assertions:

```
(?<!\{)\{([^}]+)\}(?!\})
```

Explanation:

- `(?<!\{)`: previous character is not a `{`
- `\{([^}]+)\}`: something inside curly braces, e.g. `{foo}`
- `(?!\})`: following character is not a `}`

Comment: Add '\s' to exclude whitespaces inside curly braces: `(?<!\{)\{([^\s}]+)\}(?!\})`