# How to check if string has format arguments in Python?

Tags: python, string, formatting

I am formatting strings using named arguments with `.format()`. How can I obtain a list of arguments?

For example:

```
>>> my_string = 'I live in {city}, {state}, {country}.'
>>> get_format_args(my_string)
# ['city', 'state', 'country']
```

Note that order does not matter. I have dug a fair amount into the [string.Formatter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Formatter) documentation to no avail. I am sure you could write regex to do this, but there *must* bet a more elegant way.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It looks like you can get field names using the `Formatter.parse` method:

```
>>> import string
>>> my_string = 'I live in {city}, {state}, {country}.'
>>> [tup[1] for tup in string.Formatter().parse(my_string) if tup[1] is not None]
['city', 'state', 'country']
```

This will also return non-named arguments. Example: `"{foo}{1}{}"` will return `['foo', '1', '']`. But if necessary you can filter out the latter two by using `str.isdigit()` and comparing against the empty string respectively.

Comment: It's also documented: [`string.Formatter.parse`](https://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.Formatter.parse)

Answer (score 5):

*Regex* can solve your problem.

```
>>> import re 
>>> re.findall(r'{(.*?)}', 'I live in {city}, {state}, {country}.')
['city', 'state', 'country']
```

---

**Edit:**

To avoid matching escaped placeholders like `'{{city}}'` you should change your pattern to something like:

```
(?<=(?<!\{)\{)[^{}]*(?=\}(?!\}))
```

[**Explanation:**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12728128/regular-expression-to-match-single-bracket-pairs-but-not-double-bracket-pairs/12728199#12728199)

> ```
> (?<=      # Assert that the following can be matched before the current position
>  (?<!\{)  #  (only if the preceding character isn't a {)
> \{        #  a {
> )         # End of lookbehind
> [^{}]*    # Match any number of characters except braces
> (?=       # Assert that it's possible to match...
>  \}       #  a }
>  (?!\})   #  (only if there is not another } that follows)
> )         # End of lookahead
> ```

Comment: This approach fails with escaped placeholders like `'{{city}}'`

Comment: I prefer this since it can easily be used to find specific arguments, like when '{x:03d}' is specified and I want to see if x is an argument

Comment: This won't work for nested {} like this example from the docs: `'{0:{fill}{align}16}'`