# Regex combining negative lookbehind and lookahead to match single but not double bracket

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regex to match a single bracket but not double.

I want to match `[` but not `[[`.

It's not like this question: [Regular expression to match single bracket pairs but not double bracket pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12728128/regular-expression-to-match-single-bracket-pairs-but-not-double-bracket-pairs) as that matches the contents within but I want to the brackets themselves.

A simple lookahead matches 1 part of the double bracket which I don't want. How do I combine both lookahead and lookbehind? I want to match neither of them if they are put together in a pair.

[image]

Comment: Please provide examples of what you want as output for given input. The image seems to show what you don't want? Are you looking for `(?<!\{)\{(?!\{)`?

Comment: If yes, it is the dupe of [Regular expression to match single bracket pairs but not double bracket pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12728128/regular-expression-to-match-single-bracket-pairs-but-not-double-bracket-pairs), the same lookarounds are shown there. Or, another good dupe is [Regular Expression to match only one angle bracket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16747723/regular-expression-to-match-only-one-angle-bracket).

Comment: ...except that there the negative look-ahead concerns the closing brace, not the opening one. Yes: the second one is a good dupe!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for the second dupe.

Comment: You have to guard _both sides_ of the character: `(?<!A)A(?!A)` or it's quicker brother `A(?<!AA)(?!A)`